# File upload at shopify checkout

Tags: shopify

I need a obligatory file upload at Shopify and would like to have it on the checkout page. It is a SIM card store, so people have to identify themselves with their passport or EU ID card. As I could not find a suitable plugin it must happen in the checkout.liquid I guess.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Shopify doesn't allow any app to edit or modify the checkout page due to security reasons, if you have Shopify plus plan then you have checkout.liquid but I am not sure it allows you to upload a file or not

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I fired. Need to implement it on the product page in that case. Thank you anyway

Comment: You need to use any 3rd party app that comes with custom fields and file uploads as well

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a built-in file upload you can use with every product you sell. Line Item properties, and check the upload aspect. You do not need an App or anything special. The tutorial on using it is good enough to get most people 99% there.

Comment: Can  you please share the related link?

Comment: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-properties